# Kendo UI Large Parameters Value (414 Request-URI Too Long) error

Tags: kendo-ui, parameter-passing, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

Hy This code is part of my grid.

```
grid._parameterMap = function (data, type) {

    if (type !== "read" && data.models)
        return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };

    var warehouseCodeList = [];


    var selectedWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition = '';

    $.each(KendoData('mltWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition').dataItems(), function (index, value) {
        selectedWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition += value.WarehouseCode + ',';
    });


    selectedWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition = selectedWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition.slice(0, -1);


    var parameters = {
        warehouseCodeList: selectedWarehouse_OnPhysicalCountDefinition,
        periodDateString: $('#dpcPeriodDate_OnPhysicalCountDefinition').val(),
        Page: data.page,
        PageSize: data.pageSize
    }

    return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(parameters, type);
};
```

And parameters value is

> Page
> :
> 1
> PageSize
> :
> 50
> periodDateString
> :
> "17/10/2022"
> warehouseCodeList
> :
> "480176,480172,480003,480166,480109,480025,480090,480089,480002,480088,
> 480061,480101,480016,480009,480095,480008,480094,480093,480006,480092,480005,480091,480004,
> 480117,480033,480114,480060,480113,480163,480030,480059,2011,480157,480028,480045,480048,
> 480039,480029,480120,480046,480156,480049,480072,480063,480062,48006100,480071,480070,480069,
> 480068,480067,480066,480065,480064,480077,480076,480085,480084,480082,480078,480073,480075,480079,
> 480074,480083,480127,480128,480057,480129,480058,480081,480080,480141,480132,480131,480130,480140,
> 480138,480137,480136,480135,480134,480133,480146,480145,480154,480153,480151,480147,480142,480144,
> 480148,480143,480152,480139,480150,480149,480106,480126,480055,480165,480167,480100,480123,480053,
> 480096,480168,480162,480159,480158,480038,480102,480017,480013,480122,480047,480116,480032,480034,
> 480107,480040,480118,480098,480051,480110,480026,480111,480027,480108,480103,480115,480031,480035,
> 480087,480086,480036,480119,480112,480010,480097,480155,480124,480054,480019,480099,480104,480171,
> 480164,480041,480042,480121,480043,480044,480014,480052,480170,480037,480050,480012,480105,480169,
> 480161,480174,480173"

You can see that my data and that large data not going my controller becouse of that large warehouseCodeList.You can see Request below.This request is Send Get Request in Controller.If I can change Post I think gone work bu HOW! =)

> ```
> Request URL: https://zzzz/Inv/yyy/xxxx/?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&warehouseCodeList=480176%2C480172%2C480003%2C480166%2C480109%2C480025%2C480090%2C480089%2C480002%2C480088%2C480061%2C480101%2C480016%2C480009%2C480095%2C480008%2C480094%2C480093%2C480006%2C480092%2C480005%2C480091%2C480004%2C480117%2C480033%2C480114%2C480060%2C480113%2C480163%2C480030%2C480059%2C2011%2C480157%2C480028%2C480045%2C480048%2C480039%2C480029%2C480120%2C480046%2C480156%2C480049%2C480072%2C480063%2C480062%2C48006100%2C480071%2C480070%2C480069%2C480068%2C480067%2C480066%2C480065%2C480064%2C480077%2C480076%2C480085%2C480084%2C480082%2C480078%2C480073%2C480075%2C480079%2C480074%2C480083%2C480127%2C480128%2C480057%2C480129%2C480058%2C480081%2C480080%2C480141%2C480132%2C480131%2C480130%2C480140%2C480138%2C480137%2C480136%2C480135%2C480134%2C480133%2C480146%2C480145%2C480154%2C480153%2C480151%2C480147%2C480142%2C480144%2C480148%2C480143%2C480152%2C480139%2C480150%2C480149%2C480106%2C480126%2C480055%2C480165%2C480167%2C480100%2C480123%2C480053%2C480096%2C480168%2C480162%2C480159%2C480158%2C480038%2C480102%2C480017%2C480013%2C480122%2C480047%2C480116%2C480032%2C480034%2C480107%2C480040%2C480118%2C480098%2C480051%2C480110%2C480026%2C480111%2C480027%2C480108%2C480103%2C480115%2C480031%2C480035%2C480087%2C480086%2C480036%2C480119%2C480112%2C480010%2C480097%2C480155%2C480124%2C480054%2C480019%2C480099%2C480104%2C480171%2C480164%2C480041%2C480042%2C480121%2C480043%2C480044%2C480014%2C480052%2C480170%2C480037%2C480050%2C480012%2C480105%2C480169%2C480161%2C480174%2C480173&periodDateString=17%2F10%2F2022&Page=1&PageSize=50
> Request Method: GET
> Status Code: 200 OK
> ```

And Finaly I try the give dataSource remote but not work .But I can give that data ın Ajax call.Can you Help me ?

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `type` option for the [dataSource transport configuration](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.read#transportreadtype) that you can set. It will set the type of request the dataSource would make ("POST", "GET", "PUT" or "DELETE").

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aleksandar.The code I use is below

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      /* omitted for brevity */
      type: "POST"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```